# Why does ng-init="things = […]; currentThing = things[0]" with ng-click="currentThing=thing" not update a bound value?

Tags: angularjs

See the minimal AngularJS app below.

My expectation was that clicking a `li` would change the name and number in the paragraph, but they don't change away from their original value. Any ideas why?

```
<div ng-app ng-init="things=[ { name: 'one', num: 1 }, { name: 'two', num: 2 } ]; currentThing = things[0]">
  <p>name: {{currentThing.name}} num: {{currentThing.num}}</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-click="currentThing=thing" ng-repeat="thing in things">{{thing.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Editable, runnable JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JbfZ5/1/

Comment: Tried with a controller instead of ng-init; same thing http://jsfiddle.net/JbfZ5/2/

Comment: But if I do `ng-click=doIt(thing)` and do `$scope.currentThing = thing` in that method in the controller, it does work. Why? http://jsfiddle.net/JbfZ5/3/

Comment: Changing `currentThing` to `things.currentThing` also works for some reason: http://jsfiddle.net/JbfZ5/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that when using `ng-repeat` each template instance gets its own scope and due to how prototypal inheritance works in JavaScript.

In short, when you click a `li` element it will create the currentThing property on the newly created child scope belonging to the template, instead of updating `currentThing` of the parent.

If you use this instead and click the second `li` you will notice that it updates its own scope:

```
<li ng-click="currentThing=thing" ng-repeat="thing in things">
  <pre>{{ currentThing | json }}</pre>
</li>
```

*Demo*: http://jsfiddle.net/A3eCe/

The recommended way to get around this is to use an object, for example:

```
<div ng-app ng-init="viewModel = { things: [ { name: 'one', num: 1 }, { name: 'two', num: 2 } ] }; viewModel.currentThing = viewModel.things[0]">
    <p>name: {{ viewModel.currentThing.name}} num: {{ viewModel.currentThing.num}}</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-click="viewModel.currentThing = thing" ng-repeat="thing in viewModel.things">{{thing.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*Demo:* http://jsfiddle.net/4suvy/

An excellent explanation on the issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/2887841).